# Request.Post method not working properly in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I building  quiz app. i creted 3 model Quiz , Question ,Answer 
Question is linked with Quiz by foreign key and Answer is linked with Question.i provided boolean field to the answer.
I  created radio button but its not wotking .
it showing **error : MultiValueDictKeyError at /quiz/2/11/ 'choice'**

views.py

```
def question_detail(request,question_id,quiz_id):
q = Quiz.objects.get(pk=quiz_id)
que = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
ans = que.answer_set.all()
selected_choice = que.answer_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
if selected_choice is True:
    come = que.rank
    came = come + 1
    later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=came)
    return render(request,'app/question_detail.html',{'que':que , 'later_question':later_question, 'ans':ans})
else:
    come = que.rank
    later_question = q.question_set.get(rank=come)
    return render(request, 'app/question_detail.html', {'que': que, 'later_question': later_question, 'ans': ans})
```

question_detail.html

```
<form action="{% 'app:detail' quiz_id=quiz.id question_id=que.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in que.answer_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{forloop.counter}}" value="{{choice.id}}">
    <label for="choice{{forloop.counter}}">{{choice.answer}}</label>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that 'choice' is not present in dictionary. To avoid this problem you sould use `equest.POST.get('choice')` and if the key does not exist in dict it will return `None` so eventually you'll get an error anyways. Your problem is that there is no 'choice' in request.POST try to resolve it or add some more code.

Comment: Can you `print(request.POST)` at the beginning of the function